# C++/CLI mixed mode debugging hangs (Frequently)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, visual-c++, c++-cli, mixed-mode

I am facing a process hang problem while debugging in mixed mode C++/CLI with a native application. This is unbearable, almost 70% of my debugging this happens and I need to restart the process again and again.

Is there any hotfix or solution for this?

Comment: Did you check it under different conditions?  Like does it do this when debugging other programs too?  Does it hang at a particular point?  Do you have enough memory?  etc.

Comment: Enough memory available. it is not related with system resources. It is known issue with reported bug to MSFT regarding C++/CLI bugs.

Comment: Oh, ok.  Just trying to come up with things off of the top of my head.  What does their bug report say to do about it?

Comment: VS2010 Service Pack 1 does not help with this?

Comment: Would you share the link to the reported bug?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/0cf161cd-bf14-4a1f-9e00-315505114c31
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/476040/mixed-debugger-hangs
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/574793/vs-2010-hangs-frequently-when-debugging

Comment: One of your connect links mentions turning off all Managed Debugging Assistants, perhaps that can help.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to do is, from native code avoiding stepping into managed code.  For me, that crashes my processes 100% of the time.  Instead, place a breakpoint in the managed code that you want to get to.  Debugging C++/CLI is awkward at best, usually flaky, though it is much improved over VS2008.

Not sure if you are running into this exact scenario.

EDIT:  I have been having much better luck (in terms of stability) debugging C++/CLI on Win7, as compared with my WinXP dev machine.